# Text not centered using crossaxisalignment

Tags: layout, flutter

I am using crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, but somehow the text 'Logo' is just not centered.  Really not too sure what is causing it and am I missing something here.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 100.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Logo',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Flutter docs about `Container`:

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. **Containers with children size themselves to their children.** The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

Your `Column` and `Text('Logo')` aren't big enough to use all screen width, so `Container` doesn't use all screen width as you can see in the image (taken with [Dart DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview), which is very useful for debug)

[image]

You can add more widgets to your `Column` and the width will grow as they use it, **or just add `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to your `Container`** to take up all the available width of the parent.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 100.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Logo',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Henrique, your answer is to the point, but I just wanted to point out that instead of using **double.infinity** you should use **MediaQuery.of(context).size.width**, this will ensure that you take up all the available width of the parent instead of going to infinity.

Comment: @ShubhamBhardwaj indeed that makes more sense than going to infinity, I edited my answer. Thanks for the tip.